# ExFat-fuse hot- removal ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mount, exfat, udisks, fuse

My users keep removing USB disks formatted with Exfat and the files written end up having 0 bytes afterward.
I know that the ideal case would be to unmount properly, but it is pretty bad that everything is lost after the mistake.

**How can I make the filesystem sync when it is mounted with udisk2?**

Ubuntu 18.04 uses udisks 2.7 which does not implement overrides:

- udisks 2.7 : http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/2.7.0/ -> no Configurable mount options section
- later: http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/2.9.0/ -> section added

Can I override using udev rules? how would this look like?
Does anyone have any other ideas?

I have been running experiments and this will definitely get better with later ubuntu releases because of the non-fuse fs and later udisk2, but for the time being, I have ubuntu 18 and I would like to get some sort of robustness.
Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 18 would mean you are using Ubuntu Core 18 as this is the only version of Ubuntu to use single digit version numbers. If this is not correct please edit the question and correct. BTW Ubuntu 18.04 is EOL in just a few months. Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS will reach the end of its hardware and maintenance update LTS support window on April 30, 2023.

Comment: 18 is not a single digit?